# Polynomial Sum of Squares is a Square

Tags: polynomials

If $l_1$ and $l_2$ are linear forms in $\mathbb{C}[x, y]$, then $l_1^2 + l_2^2$ is a square if and only if one of the $l_i = 0$ or they scalar multiples of each other.

What is the analogous statement for three linear forms $l_1$, $l_2$, $l_3$ in $\mathbb{C}[x, y, z]$? Clearly the sum $l_1^2 + l_2^2 + l_3^2$ is a square if the nonzero $l_i$ are scalar multiples of each other, but is this the only possibility for it to be a square?

Comment: Not sure I get this fully but what happens if you consider $(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{2}})^2 + (\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{2}})^2 + i^2 = x^2$ ?

Comment: @AydinGerek, those are not linear forms. A linear form is homogeneous linear polynomial, so $l_i = ax + by + cz$, where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I see. How do you feel about $(\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}})^2 + (\frac{x-y}{\sqrt{2}})^2 + (iy)^2 = x^2$ then?

Comment: @AydinGerek, Excellent! Then it is clearly possible to write a square as a sum of three linear forms that are not multiples of each other.

Answer (score 2):

The analogous statement does not hold. Even in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ it is possible for the squares of three linear forms to add up to another square and for these linear forms not to be scalar multiples of each other. For an example consider:

$$ \left(\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{x-y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2   + (iy)^2 = x^2$$

Comment: A related question which I cannot immediately answer is whether the statement with two squares holds in $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ or indeed in polynomial rings with even greater number of variables.

Comment: Suppose there are two squares such that their sum is a square: $l_1^2(x,y,z,\dots)+l_2^2(x,y,z,\dots)=p^2(x,y,z,\dots)$. Then $l_1^2=(p-l_2)(p+l_2)$. Then it follows that $l_1^2=0$ (ans, consequently, $l_1=0$) on the **union** of the sets defined by $p-l_2=0$ and $p+l_2=0$. What are these sets? (Hyper)planes. Can a union of two hyperplanes itself be a hyperplane? Yeah, if they coincide.